# Minimal debian latex installation and errors compiling simple file

Tags: errors, installing

Really new to latex (2 hours, and google was not my friend).

I installed latex with:

```
# aptitude install texlive-base lmodern+M texlive-lang-portuguese+M
```

(had to manually install texlive-lang-portuguese afterwards, this didnt work)

Now, when compiling even the most simple document, I get this errors:

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.15 (TeX Live 2015/dev/Debian) (preloaded format=pdftex 2018.9.10)  13 SEP 2018 13:13
entering extended mode
 restricted \write18 enabled.
 %&-line parsing enabled.
**ata.tex
(./ata.tex
! Undefined control sequence.
l.1 \documentclass
                  {article}
? 
! Undefined control sequence.
l.3 \usepackage
               [utf8]{inputenc}
? 
! Undefined control sequence.
l.12 \begin
           {document}
?
```

What is wrong with it? Do I miss packages, or fonts or whatever?... Or do I have to configure anything prior to compilation?...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was a package missing:

```
texlive-latex-base
```

I was using pdftex to compile. Needed to use pdflatex.
Now it seems to work.